# NextJS 13.3.2 : How to read and send a file from NextJS API side?

Tags: typescript, file, amazon-s3, next.js, upload

I am attempting to send files (such as PDFs and images) using FormData from Postman (for test, then'll be client side). I have created a key/value pair of file/myfile.png in the Body>form-data section.

However, I am having trouble processing these files on the API side (/api/file.route.ts) and am currently stuck. My ultimate goal is to send these files to AWS S3, but I need to figure out how to process them first.

I have tried using formidable and other methods, but I am still unable to make progress. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Thank you.

One of my tries

```ts
const formidableParse = async (req: NextApiRequest) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) =>
      err ? reject(err) : resolve([fields, files])
    )
  );

export async function POST(request: NextApiRequest) {
  // Get formData from request
  const [fields, files]:any = await formidableParse(request);
  console.log(files)
  return NextResponse.json({status:201})

}
```